# Need to scan an object that is an array in another class

Tags: java, class

My deck create an array of Card objects, and it prints out successfully that it is updated. I want to make a third class to implement the program: create a deck object, ask players how many card they want and then pass them out randomly. In the PlayingTable class at the bottom I try to create an instance of a deck and scan it to make all the information in the deck is there. It says I can't scan a deck object because it's not an array, and I'm not quite sure where to go from here....

Here's my code for the two classes:

public class Card

{

```
    //Instance properties//
    private String cardNum; 
    private String cardSuit;

    //Instance Methods // 
    //Constructor, create an instance of card
    public Card( String num , String suit ) 
    {
        System.out.println( "Creating a card.");
        cardNum = num ;
        cardSuit = suit;    
    }       
     public void display()
     { 
    System.out.println("This card is a" + " "+ cardNum + cardSuit);
    }
```

}

public class Deck

{
     // Instance properties//

```
 //Number of cards in a deck
 public static int numCards = 52; 
 private static Card [ ] deck= new Card [numCards];
 private static String [ ] cardValue = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" } ;
 private static String [ ] cardSuit = { " of Hearts" , " of Spades", " of Clubs", " of Diamonds" };

 //Instance methods and Constructor//
 /*public void Deck ( )
 {


 }*/

 public static void fillDeck ( )
 {

    int eachCard = 0 ;

    for ( int i = 0; i < cardValue.length ; i++ )
    {
     for ( int j = 0 ; j < cardSuit.length ; j++ )
        {

         deck[eachCard++] = new Card ( cardValue [i] , cardSuit [j] );

        }
     } 
 }

public static void getDeck ()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < numCards ; i++ )
   {
    fillDeck();
    //System.out.println( " This is card" + i + " " + " of the deck" );
    deck[i].display();
    }
}   
public static void main (String [] args ) 
{ 
    getDeck();
}
```

}

public class PlayingTable
{
        static Deck dealersDeck = new Deck();

```
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {  

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 52; i++)
        {
              System.out.println ( dealersDeck[i].getDeck());
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Please clean up your code and retag this with the language you're working in. Also point out exactly which line is causing you trouble.

Comment: I'm not even well read enough to clean it yet, but it's my for loop giving me trouble..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: How do I display information form one class ... [from] ... another class?

A: Provide public "getter" methods (or, if you're programming #, "properties") in the "other class".

Here's a good tutorial on C# properties:

- http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/properties/#.UJ79KlZz2So

And a discussion on Java "getter/setter" methods:

- http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/13283/getset-methods-in-java

Finally, here's a discussion on OO "encapsulation", an issue that actually transcends "properties", "getter/setter methods" ... *AND* ... "displaying information in one class from another":

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Answer (score 0):

You create an array that will hold Card objects initialized to the size of numCards -1

```
private static Card [ ] deck = new Card [numCards-1];
```

But you never put any objects in it,  so when you call

```
deck[i].display();
```

You're calling the display method on something that doesn't exist, you have a method that will populate the array(makeDeck()), but you never call it.

Having a main() inside an entity class file can be convenient, but can also mask errors in your code.  I recommend you do your testing in a separate class.

Comment: ok, so i got it to print. but now my for loop keeps returning j (which is giving each card a value incrementing up form 0-13) as only 13... I can't figure out why it wont increment j, I tried to tweak ti a bit but the same result

Comment: Look at your inner loop, you're using i in the conditionals when you should be using j, that's for the incrementing and stop condition

Comment: i changed it to j with no luck, i meant to post my new for loop but i'm new to the site and didnt know how. I'll edit my old one..sorry

Comment: Still your inner loop, add some debug statements and you'll see what you're doing.  You're iterating over those cards more than 700 times.  Every card gets set to 13 because for each iteration of i, you set each card to 0,1,2 ...13.  Also with the code you have now your deck will only have 50 cards.